# TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [parameter stack size=10000]

Tags: errors, linguistics, gb4e, rmarkdown, bookdown

I am a Spanish linguist working on writing my dissertation using RMarkdown. My document was compiling fine into a pdf until I tried to add examples and glosses using the gb4e package. I am working on a Mac running Big Sur 11.1, pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020), R 4.0.3, and RStudio Version 1.3.1073.

I started with a small rdm document until I had it working fine. I ran into the problem  when I moved the chunk into the actual manuscript that I get the error "TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [parameter stack size=10000]".

Here's the toy document that does compile fine:

```
---
title: "testing_latex"
author: "Erwin Lares"
date: "1/5/2021"
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
- \usepackage{gb4e}
---

See (\ref{stm-n-lit}) shows the literal sentence. (\ref{stm-n-idm}) shows the idiomatic sentence. (\ref{stm-plain}) shows an unambiguous sentence that can only be interpreted compositionally.

\begin{exe} % sets up the top-level example environment
\ex 
\begin{xlist} % first embedding (alphabetical numbering)
\ex\label{stm-n-lit}
    \gll Mary kicked the bucket, she stubbed her toes. \\
    Mary kick-PAST the bucket, 3S bruised-PAST 3S-POSS toe-PL \\
    \trans ‘Mary made contact with the bucket with her toes forcefully ’
\ex\label{stm-n-idm}
    \gll Mary kicked the bucket, she's dead. \\
    Mary kick-PAST the bucket, 3S COP-PRE dead-adj \\
    \trans ‘Mary is dead.’
\end{xlist} % end first embedding
\ex\label{stm-plain} 
    \gll This example does not contain sub examples.\\
     DEMO-SING example DO-helping NEG contain sub examples\\
    \trans ‘This is a plain example’
\end{exe}
```

The problem comes up when I include this piece of code in my manuscript. When I try to knit my document, something breaks and produces the error in question. Here's a copy of the manuscript. I realize that the output in the YAML is different, but I need a pdf_document2 for the bookdown package. Any suggestions would be most appreciated.

```
---
title: "Experimental Design"
author: "Erwin Lares"
date: "12/23/2020"
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2: default
  bookdown::html_document2: default
header-includes:
- \usepackage{graphicx}
- \usepackage{float}
- \usepackage{longtable}
- \usepackage{gb4e}
---

<!-- code_folding: hide -->


{r loading-library, include=FALSE, echo=FALSE}
#install.packages("networkD3")

#library(networkD3)
library(tidyverse)
library(DataEditR)
#library(gt)
library(kableExtra)
library(tinytex)
library(rmarkdown)
library(bookdown)
library(knitr)
library(skimr)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(broom)

\begin{exe} % sets up the top-level example environment
\ex 
\begin{xlist} % first embedding (alphabetical numbering)
\ex\label{stm-n-lit}
    \gll Mary kicked the bucket, she stubbed her toes. \\
    Mary kick-PAST the bucket, 3S bruised-PAST 3S-POSS toe-PL \\
    \trans ‘Mary made contact with the bucket with her toes forcefully ’
\ex\label{stm-n-idm}
    \gll Mary kicked the bucket, she's dead. \\
    Mary kick-PAST the bucket, 3S COP-PRE dead-adj \\
    \trans ‘Mary is dead.’
\end{xlist} % end first embedding
\ex\label{stm-plain} 
    \gll This example does not contain sub examples.\\
     DEMO-SING example DO-helping NEG contain sub examples\\
    \trans ‘This is a plain example’
\end{exe}
```

Answer (score 0):

As it happens I ran into the answer to someone else's question that also solved mine.

Adding a `\noautomath` right after `\usepackage{gb4e}` to the YAML header caused my document to compile just fine.

Thanks for the help I know was coming my way!

Comment: However, in your example the HTML output have no sense, since all the LaTeX stuff will be ignored. Moreover, usually you do not need to include  packages  graphicx and longtable in the YAML header, as knitr will do automatically when needed. That is, `![](example-image)` will work even without any YAML header.

Comment: Thanks Fran! I kept graphics and longtable because the bookdown cookbook suggests I do. My tables can go over one page long and I have finer control over images.